# Spawned object doesn't spawn again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in a mobile game that has multiples areas in the same scene. Each area has a trigger and when the player enters in it several objects are spawned to pick up them. How can I do to deactivate a picked up object so when the player enters in this area again this object doesn't spawn again?

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PathologicalGames;

public class InOutZone_ZONAS: MonoBehaviour {

//Objetos
[Header("Objetos")]
public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;
private GameObject[] despawnObjects;


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        SpawnObjectsZ ();
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        GameObject[] despawnObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ItemZona");
        for (int i = 0; i < despawnObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            PoolManager.Pools ["Objetos"].Despawn (despawnObjects[i].transform);
            Debug.Log("Despawnea Objetos");
        }
    }
}
void SpawnObjectsZ()
{
    foreach (GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions) {
        int selection = Random.Range (0, spawnObjects.Count);
        PoolManager.Pools ["Objetos"].Spawn (spawnObjects [selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your current code that doesn't work.

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: Ok. Good. Please explain what Object the `InOutZone_ZONAS` script is attazched to. The pick-up item or the location where player is detected?

Comment: I add the objects to pick up in spawnObjects list and objects location in spawnPositions. This works ok. But I don't know how to deactivate the objects that the player picks up so when he enters in this area again the objects don't spawn again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do to deactivate a picked up object so when the player
>   enters in this area again this object doesn't spawn again?

There are many ways to do this. You can simply remove the GameObject from the `List` after you spawn it with `spawnObjects.Remove(spawnObjects[selection]);`

```
public class Playervitals : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Objetos
    [Header("Objetos")]
    public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
    public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;
    private GameObject[] despawnObjects;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            SpawnObjectsZ();
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            GameObject[] despawnObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ItemZona");
            for (int i = 0; i < despawnObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                PoolManager.Pools["Objetos"].Despawn(despawnObjects[i].transform);
                Debug.Log("Despawnea Objetos");
            }
        }
    }

    void SpawnObjectsZ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spawnPositions.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject spawnPosition = spawnPositions[i];
            int selection = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
            PoolManager.Pools["Objetos"].Spawn(spawnObjects[selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
            spawnObjects.Remove(spawnObjects[selection]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this remove the list before spawn the objects... What I want is spawn the objects so the player can pick up some of this, and when he exits the area and enters again, the objects picked don't spawn anymore. I suppose that I have to implement any kind of check if they are picked or not.

Comment: "I suppose that I have to implement any kind of check if they are picked or not" That's another option. "But this remove the list before spawn the objects" **No**. It spawns it then removes it from the `List`. The GameObject is not destroyed. It's just removed from the `List` so that it wont be spawned again. Test that and let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: Sorry! I had not checked your solution. It works !! And how can I do it only if the player has picked up a concrete object of the list?

Comment: @Angelsm Is there a pick-up attached to your GameObject. Please post it and then I will take it from there.

Comment: If I add this condition in the despawn I think it could work. Player.GetComponent<vItemManager>().ContainItem(id10)); How can I do it?

Comment: Any idea? How can I deactivate the object if this condition take place so this object doesn't spawn again?